# Vector size cannot be NA

Tags: r

I am running following code:

```
TrainSet$volume <- factor(TrainSet$volume)
model1 <- randomForest(volume ~ ., data = TrainSet, importance = TRUE)
```

It gave me the following error:

> NAs introduced by coercion
>
> NAs produced by integer overflow
>
> Error in integer(nclass * nsample) : vector size cannot be NA

I have checked

```
length(TrainSet$volume)
```

which gave me

```
[1] 126671
```

So any ideas why I get that error?

Comment: Make a R reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: The most important part of this error message is `integer overflowError`. Google this.

Comment: It is kaggle data `https://www.kaggle.com/ehallmar/daily-historical-stock-prices-1970-2018`

Comment: I checked it, I think it would be good idea to decrease the sample size.